# How to insert a list of values into a column in sqlite3 with python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I can't seem to get `executemany` to work. I didn't get any errors. But no values got inserted either. The following is a small example: the table prices already has some columns and 3 rows. I added a new column `t` and inserted the values in `vals` into `t`.

```
vals = [(1,), (2,), (3,)] 
cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE prices ADD COLUMN t REAL') #"
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO TABLE prices(t) VALUES(?)", vals)
data = cursor.execute("SELECT id, t FROM prices")

for i in data:
    print i
```

I get

```
(1, None)
(2, None)
(3, None)
```

Comment: Your syntax for `insert` seems to be incorrect. Please copy-paste a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: When I fix your syntax error and add the appropriate wrapper code, I cannot reproduce your result. See [here](http://ideone.com/vmVw0s) for your code working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

it does't look like you're inserting values into the column 't'.i'm assuming your table has 2 columns (id,t)
Check your list on top which has

```
vals = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
```

perhaps that's the problem. Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Actually, my table has more than 2 columns. Column ```t``` is the last one added. I stated this in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You have actually successfully inserted the values into the table. The problem is that they are new rows at the bottom.
If you do a fetch all you'll have

```
(col1, col2, ..., none)
.
.
.
(none, none, ..., 1)
```

this is because the `INSERT INTO` command adds rows.

Rob's example worked because he didn't have existing columns in the table.

You need to update with a `WHERE` clause:
although this is slow and I'd like to speed up

```
add_col_str = 'ALTER TABLE orig ADD COLUMN {} INT'.format(col_name)
db.execute(add_col_str) 

for i in range(len(df)):
    add_data_str = "UPDATE orig SET {} =(?) WHERE orig_id=(?)".format(col_name)
    value = int(df.values[i])
    idx = df.index[i]
    db.execute(add_data_str, (value, idx))
# commit
db.commit()
```